# Use Laravel route to access storage subfolders

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I got inspired of this [post](https://laravel.io/forum/04-23-2015-securing-filesimages) to securely access files within my storage.

The post suggests to use the following route:

```
Route::get('file/{filename}', 'FileController@getFile')->where('filename', '^[^/]+$');
```

So I can access any file like `http://yoursite.com/file/secret.jpg`

**Problem** what if `{filename}` contains a `subfolder + filename`?
The url would look like `http://yoursite.com/file/personal/secret.jpg`.
The route wouldn't be found.

I may also have many levels of subfolders.

**Possible solution**
As a temporary solution, I though of replacing `http://yoursite.com/file/personal/secret.jpg` by `http://yoursite.com/file/personal|secret.jpg` so `{filename}` would be equal to `personal|secret.jpg`. And in the getFile method, I would replace the `|` by `/`. But it looks like an *ugly solution*.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: The only thing keeping it from loading images in subfolders is the where() statement at the end.  If you remove that, you will be able to load images from subfolders, but this could open up a security risk.

Comment: No!, I've just tried without the  `where` at the end of the route.
I get 
`(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
in RouteCollection.php` which means that the route is not found. which makes sens. because there are no route that has `/file/{param1}/{param2}` or `/file/personal/{filename}`

Comment: Yep, not sure what I was thinking...

Comment: You could just open up the where() regex completely.... `->where('filename', '.+')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even you can try regular expression in the where condition.

Something like this.

```
Route::get('file/{filename}', function ($filename) {
    dd($filename);
})->where('filename', '^(.+)\/([^\/]+)$');
```

Tested and working with file/filename.jpg or file/files/files/filename.jpg etc.

Answer (score 5):

What you could do is define a pattern for that route param.

At the top of your routes file add:

```
Route::pattern('filename', '[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_\/]+');
```

Also, you will need to remove your `where` clause for the Route:

```
Route::get('file/{filename}', 'FileController@getFile');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works! but does the regex `[a-z0-9.\/]+` means you allow only alphanumeric characters? Because I may also have files containing `_` or other conventional authorized characters as part of a file names.